# How to add XML documentation comments to Xamarin iOS Bindings Library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xml-documentation, xml-comments

I am implementing Xamarin iOS Bindings Library to bind an Objective-C framework.
I would like it to contain XML documentation comments if it's even possible.

Is there any way to grab them from Objective-C Headers or at least to add them manually to the resulting bound classes somehow?

I tried adding XML comments to interfaces described in `ApiDefinitions.cs`, but the generated classes in `obj/Debug/ios/Namespace/*.g.cs` remain undocumented, the XML documentation file also remains empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mdoc` to generate the XML documentation for bindings. You can find an example here https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/Rules.make#L7

Answer (score 1):

[This manual](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodoc/generating-documentation/) was useful to generate the documentation. The next steps are done:

1. Add a mdoc tools folder to my solution taken from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/tools/mdoc).
2. Add an empty Mdoc folder to the Bindings project. It will contain generated mdoc documentation files.
3. Add the following lines to the post-build event of the Bindings project:

```bash
$(SolutionDir)tools\mdoc\mdoc update -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0" --out $(ProjectDir)Mdoc $(TargetPath)
$(SolutionDir)tools\mdoc\mdoc export-msxdoc $(ProjectDir)Mdoc
```

The first line generates or updates a bunch of XML files in the Mdoc folder. These files can be included to the project (with Build Action None) and filled with your documentation manually or using the [Monodoc browser](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodoc/). Next time the project is rebuilt, the files will be updated without removing the already written documentation. Check the [mdoc-update](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3Amdoc-update(1)) for details.

The second line converts the Monodoc XML files to Microsoft XML Documentation file that can be shipped along with the output DLL file. Check the [mdoc-export-msxdoc](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3Amdoc-export-msxdoc(1)) for details.

Comment: Hi Olexander, whats the path you mentioned in first line to post bild event.

Comment: @raheem52, from the [mdoc-update](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3Amdoc-update(1))  
"-L, --lib=DIRECTORY - 
Add DIRECTORY to the assembly search path, so that dependencies of ASSEMBLIES can be found without documenting those assemblies."  
- In this case this is Xamarin.iOS reference libraries path.